# MYSQL Sum Query with IF Condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum

I am building a query for a report with multiple IF conditions on the SUM. I am having problems with a multiple IF conditions on the SUM.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(`totalamount`) AS Total, 
SUM(`PayPalFee`) AS Fees,
DATE(`TransactionDate`) AS `Day`, 
SUM(IF(PaymentType = "paypal", 1,0)) AS Paypal, 
SUM(IF(PaymentType = "check", 1,0)) AS Checks, 
SUM(IF(PaymentType = "credit card", 1,0)) AS CreditCard, 
COUNT(*) AS Entries
 FROM my_table
 WHERE TransactionDate between '2011-05-05' AND '2012-01-30'
 GROUP BY day
 ORDER BY `day` ASC
```

This query works just fine.

When I try to add the below conditional SUM statement:

```
 SUM('TotalAmount'(PaymentType = "credit card", 1,0)) AS CreditCardTotal,
```

This conditional IF statement fails out.

I have a column called 'TotalAmount' and a column called 'PaymentType' I am looking to create a SUM of the credit card transactions by each day, a SUM of the checks transactions by each day, a SUM of the paypal transactions by each day,. 
I have tried to create a subquery but this returns a value for the entire TotalAmount column, not broken down by day.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try with a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) in this way :

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN PaymentType = "credit card" 
    THEN TotalAmount 
    ELSE 0 
END) AS CreditCardTotal,
```

Should give what you are looking for ...

Comment: @aleroot is there any difference between `SUM(CASE WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END)` and `SUM(IF(.., .., ..))` when I would like check only one condition (if some boolean field is 1)? I mean, which one should be faster?

Comment: Could be done as an if eg: `SUM(IF(PaymentType = "credit card", TotalAmount, 0) AS CreditCardTotal,`

Comment: @George: Yes, I believe IF is equivalent.

Comment: @NHG: I suspect that the performance is identical, but I haven't tested.

Comment: I just tested with large amount of rows and got same performance

Comment: See [MySQL - CASE vs IF Statement vs IF function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30047983/711006) for syntax and use case differences (no perfomance comparison though).

Answer (score 67):

How about this?

```
SUM(IF(PaymentType = "credit card", totalamount, 0)) AS CreditCardTotal
```

Comment: It doesn't work in MsSql. the (IF) statement is doing something else.

Comment: @Sayedidrees: OK, but the question was about MySQL.