# MySQL - CASE vs IF Statement vs IF function

Tags: mysql

Who can please explain the difference between `CASE`-statement, `IF`-statement and `IF`-function?

What is the difference in terms of usage and "how it works"?

Comment: the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[From the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), it looks like the `if` function is just a less flexible form of the `case` expression.  For example, you could write:

```
select if(username = 'darxysaq', 'high', 'low') as awesomeness
```

And the equivalent with `case`:

```
select case when username = 'darxysaq' then 'high' else 'low' end as awesomeness
```

But `case` is more flexible.  It allows more than one branch, like:

```
select case 
       when username = 'darxysaq' then 'high' 
       when username = 'john skeet' then 'medium' 
       else 'low' 
       end as awesomeness
```

And it can act like a `switch`:

```
select case username 
       when 'darxysaq' then 'high' 
       when 'john skeet' then 'medium' 
       else 'low' 
       end as awesomeness
```

Now the `if` statement is an entirely different beast. It is a [control statement in MySQL procedures](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php).  The statement form looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAwesomeness (username varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(20)
BEGIN
   IF username = 'darxysaq' THEN
      return 'high';
   ELSEIF username = 'john skeet' THEN
      return 'medium';
   ELSE
     return 'low';
   END IF;
END; //
```

[Here's a SQL Fiddle with the statement version.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1b5c/1/0)  It looks like Mr Bean isn't all that he's made up to be!

A final note: the `case` expression is standard SQL and works in most databases.  The `if` function is not standard SQL and will not work in other databases, like SQL Server or PostgreSQL.