# Combine similar mysql SUM queries where one has an extra WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

We have the following basic queries to calculate two sums:

```
SELECT SUM(col_x) AS sum_id FROM table WHERE col_y=1
SELECT SUM(col_x) AS sum_id FROM table WHERE col_y=1 AND col_z=2
```

Is there a way we can efficiently combine these into one query that returns each sum, hopefully where the second query filters on the results of the first?

Comment: These are the worst comments I've ever seen on stack overflow. Calculate? Well, its a `SUM` query, so I guess I want the average? What do you tink it means? Combine? These are two queries, I would like to only make one query. Filter on? I assumed the first query returned a set of results and the second could filter on those, as it's just adding one condition to an existing query.

Comment: You can combine using `UNION` so each sum is a row or combine where each sum is a different field. That is why you should provide a desire output to make clear what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do:

```
SELECT
    SUM(`points`) AS `all_sum`, 
    SUM(IF(`type` = 'basic', `points`, 0)) AS `basic_sum` -- Only count the points if the type is basic
FROM
    `events`
WHERE
    `status` = 2 -- Only look at rows where the status is 2
```

You can certainly use `CASE` as well, but for this question, `IF` might be easier to read (it's a preference). [MySQL - CASE vs IF Statement vs IF function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047983/mysql-case-vs-if-statement-vs-if-function)