# how to pass the parent's value into sub-query or sub sub-query

Tags: mysql

Please refer to the example query below::

```
    SELECT
    a.id,
    a.status,
    a.updated_at,
    b.id,
    b.updated_at,
    IF((a.status = 1 OR a.status = 2), 
   (IF(a.status = 1), 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coconut c WHERE c.datetime BETWEEN a.updated_at AND b.updated_at) , 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coconut c WHERE c.datetime BETWEEN a.updated_at AND NOW()) ), 0) AS 'ab'
    FROM apple a
    LEFT JOIN banana b
```

The sub-queries inside IF condition are the issue that gave me error message: "unknown column a.updated_at" and "unknown column b.updated_at" when I'm trying to get the data from table `apple` and table `banana`.

Is there any other way to pass the value from table `apple` and table `banana` into the sub-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your counts through a `CASE` statement (essentially a *IF-THEN-ELSE statement*), which is more flexible than the `IF` function because it allows more than one branch (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047983/mysql-case-vs-if-statement-vs-if-function) about it from a previous question). Also, don't forget to include your `JOIN` conditions after `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.status,
a.updated_at,
b.id,
b.updated_at,
CASE WHEN (a.status = 1) THEN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coconut c WHERE c.datetime BETWEEN a.updated_at AND b.updated_at)
     WHEN (a.status = 2) THEN 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coconut c WHERE c.datetime BETWEEN a.updated_at AND NOW())
     ELSE 0
END AS 'ab'
FROM apple a
LEFT JOIN banana b ON a.id = b.id
```