# mysql aggregate query returning wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, mysql-8.0

I have data in two tables that i need to join and return the count of occurences of a record in one of the tables,

The data in Employee table looks like,

```
empId  workpatternId
    1        20
```

The data in the workPattern tables looks like,

```
workpatternId  monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
   20           ALL     ALL     ALL       ALL     NULL   NULL     ALL
```

The following query should return 5, which is the count of ALL, but returns 7 instead,

```
SELECT empId,b.workingPatternId, COUNT(monday='ALL') +
 COUNT(tuesday='ALL') + COUNT(wednesday='ALL')+ COUNT(thursday='ALL') + 
    COUNT(friday='ALL')+ COUNT(saturday='ALL')+ COUNT(sunday='ALL') AS COUNT
      FROM workPattern b 
 join Employee e on (e.workpatternId = b.workpatternId) and e.empId = 1
         GROUP BY empId ;
```

what is wrong with the query?

EDIT

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8854c4dbef96e31bfa78798a9212dd43)

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: You can't use COUNT for this. Use `SUM` with `ISNULL` function instead.

Comment: @Tajni NULL in this case is text

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732036/mysql-sum-query-with-if-condition

Comment: @Tajni replacing the count with sum seems to have resolved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point for aggregation, since it seems you have just one row in `workPattern` per `empId`. You could just write this as:

```
SELECT e.empId, wp.workingPatternId, 
      (wp.monday    = 'ALL') 
    + (wp.tuesday   = 'ALL') 
    + (wp.wednesday = 'ALL') 
    + (wp.thursday  = 'ALL') 
    + (wp.friday    = 'ALL') 
    + (wp.saturday  = 'ALL') 
    + (wp.sunday    = 'ALL') cnt
FROM workPattern wp
INNER Employee e on e.workpatternId = wp.workpatternId 
WHERE e.empId = 1
```

If you need aggregation for some reason, then you want `sum()` rather than `count()`: the latter counts all non-null values, while a false condition is evaluated as `0` (which is not `null`, so it is taken into account in your query):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
          (wp.monday    = 'ALL') 
        + (wp.tuesday   = 'ALL') 
        + (wp.wednesday = 'ALL') 
        + (wp.thursday  = 'ALL') 
        + (wp.friday    = 'ALL') 
        + (wp.saturday  = 'ALL') 
        + (wp.sunday    = 'ALL')
    ) cnt
FROM workPattern wp
INNER JOIN Employee e on e.workpatternId = wp.workpatternId 
WHERE e.empId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. The data i provided is a snippet, can't possibly post all due to the volume, so yes aggregation is needed.

Comment: I think you need to edit the aggregation sql. cnt is showing 1, should be 5

Comment: @Bisoux: I don't see how the second query can return  `1`. It returns a value that is equal to, or greater than, the value returned by the first query.

Comment: I tested it and it returns 1. The first and second query are not directly related. I have posted what worked as an answer.

Comment: @Bisoux: it would help if you could set up a [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) of some sort.

Comment: I have added a dbfiddle link to the question

Comment: @Bisoux: ah yes, you were right... The conditions need to be surrounded with parentheses. I fixed the answer. I should have spotted that by myself in the first place, but I learnt something here!

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 SELECT empId,b.workingPatternId, sum(Monday='ALL') + sum(Tuesday='ALL') + sum(Wednesday='ALL')+ sum(Thursday='ALL') + sum(Friday='ALL') + sum(Saturday='ALL')+ sum(Sunday='ALL') AS COUNT
 FROM WorkPatterns b 
 JOIN Employee e 
        ON (e.workingPatternId = b.workingPatternId) 
        AND e.empId = 1   
 GROUP BY empId ;
```